# How many exotic shards are received when dismantling an infused exotic?

Tags: destiny

Dismantling an exotic item rewards one exotic shard. Infusing an exotic item *costs* one exotic shard.

If I infuse an exotic then dismantle it, do I receive one or two exotic shards? Furthermore, if I infuse twice, do I receive three exotic shards?

Answer (score 1):

Always one.  It 'costs' 1 shard to infuse, so to infuse you actually lose the shard.  (for new players, like myself, who didn't have a ton of strange coins, this is a very big wall. I have blue items at 300 and exotics at 280-290 I can't use because I don't have enough shards to infuse them.)

Side note: You get less from infusing exotics also.  80% of the difference when infusing a legendary, but only 70% of the difference when infusing an exotic. Full 5 points if only 5 point difference with legendary, full 4 points if 4 point difference with exotic.

Comment: There is a small chance to get 2 exotic shards when dismantling an exotic item.  This chance was lowered in a recent patch/hotfix though.